# does bluetooth drastically affect battery on macbook

Tags: macbook, bluetooth

I have a uni-body macbook (13").

I also have a wireless keyboard and magic mouse.

While leaving bluetooth on drastically affect my battery life?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, it's generally not *too* big, but is still big enough that you probably should turn it off when you don't need it.

Most of the Apple Reps say that it's no big deal, whereas all the tips for saving battery life on blogs say it kills your battery in 10 minutes. Who would've known?

Comment: Cool. So nothing to really worry about. Thanks!

Comment: Apple is always going to tell you that it's "no big deal." They want you to think your battery won't hold a charge so you have to buy a new one ;)

Comment: @Wuffers, this means ultimately it's upto us to understand. No authentic answer exists :-D